# How do I skip cloning and checking out from my repo in Travis CI?

Tags: travis-ci

Is there a way to specify in my `.travis.yml` for a repo `repo_x` that I do not want to clone that repo or check out any of its branches?

For example, if I have a Homebrew Tap I'm testing, I will be acquiring the components I want to test with `brew tap` and `brew install` and will have no need of any of the contents of the Tap's repo.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question and idea!

In looking at the [`.travis.yml` parser code](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-yaml/blob/master/lib/travis/yaml/nodes/git.rb), there seems to be 3 (possibly 4 options):

- depth
- submodules
- strategy
- quiet (defined elsewhere, [mentioned in docs](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/customizing-the-build#git-clone-quiet))

`git clone --depth=0` is invalid because git returns `fatal: depth 0 is not a positive number`

The best strategy for an efficient "minimal clone time/impact" for travis may be the following:

```
git:
  quiet: true
  depth = 1
  submodules = false
```

Comment: So there's no way to just suppress of skip the `git.checkout` step on Travis CI?

Comment: @orome since there's no configuration options to do that and no ability to completely override the `git` command, i think it's impossible to completely skip the step in travis-ci